# Why using InputSource fixes SAX parser when file contains special UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, xml, string, sax

I'm looking to get an explanation on why my SAX parser fails when some special UTF-8 characters are inside my XML file.

To parse the XML file I use `Document doc = builder.parse(inputSource);`

However when I use an `inputSource` it works fine:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(in));
Document doc = builder.parse(inputSource);
```

I don't quite understand why the latter works. I've seen example of it being used but there isn't an explanation on why it works.
Does the second parse a string rather than a file, therefore the encoding will be UTF-8?

Comment: Which special chars it is failing for? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Perhaps the correct encoding is being detected in one case and not in the other. Meaning, the heading of the XML file could possibly be wrong.

Comment: @Decrypter: Please examine your file in a *binary* file editor, and then post the *bytes* used to represent `£`, along with the XML document declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect your document isn't *really* in the encoding you've declared. This line:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

will use the *platform default* encoding to convert the binary data into text within `InputStreamReader`. The XML parser doesn't get to do it any more - it doesn't get to see the raw bytes.

If this is working, your XML file is probably subtly bust - it may be declaring that it's in UTF-8, but using the platform default encoding (e.g. Windows-1252). Rather than use the workaround, you should fix the XML if you have *any* choice about it.